# Amazon EMR: use .pigbootup file

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-pig, amazon-emr

Is there a way to use a .pigbootup file on amazon?
And if so, how can I do this with command line?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Default location for lookup for .pigbootup is in the user's home directory(`$HOME/.pigbootup`). You can change it via command line as below :

```
pig -Dpig.load.default.statements=/tmp/myAlternatePigBootupFile
```